# batch load csv files from cloud storage to bigquery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, batch-processing

csv files are uploaded to cloud storage every 10 minutes, I want to upload them into bigquery every 10 minutes(batch load). How do I schedule this?

I know how to upload csv into bigquery one by one using both CLI and BQ UI. But I don't know how to upload batch data with scheduling?

Comment: What's your language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a google cloud function that is triggered when a file is uploaded to the cloud storage bucket.

[Here's an example](http://tamaszilagyi.com/blog/2019/2019-02-10-serverless/) with a json file in python.